# @Cacheable - Disable auto refresh

Tags: spring, rest

I have implemented @Cacheable in my spring project and I am facing one issue.

When cache is enable and it's returning arraylist. After that I'm modifying that list as per business needs. But when my cache code hit second time and it's giving updated list that I don't need. I need only actual list.

So, Is there any feature in @Cacheable annotation to disable that auto update ?

Pls help me

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding copyOnRead="true" copyOnWrite="true" in our ehcache.xml file :)

```
<cache name="cacheName" eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="true" timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="300"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true" copyOnRead="true" copyOnWrite="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `@Cacheable` can't fit your requirement.

You can use `@CachePut`

```
@CachePut(value = "products", key = "#product.name" , unless="#result==null")
public Product updateProduct(Product product) { }
```

This annotation is used for Cache-update operation. Above method will be executed each time it gets called and result will be stored in cache [unless the #result , product in this case is null].

Comment: it's not working and even @Cacheable modifying read only arraylist also :(